# Unable to re-install macOS on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, software

After erasing my Mac I am not able to re-install macOS any way. I tried creating the bootable USB. but everytime I try installing by pressing Option, it takes me to Internet Recovery. Also post selecting Install macOS from there it always says "The Recovery Server Could not be contacted" even having good internet connection.

Comment: We need some details like specific Mac model, OS you’re trying to install, etc.  is the problem your USB won’t boot or you can’t install macOS?